# Command does not output anything when started from cron

Tags: bash, cron

When I execute this command on CentOS7 I get correct fcgi version:

```
echo fcgiversion=$(/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/yum info --cacheonly fcgi | /bin/grep -iom1 Version.* | /bin/awk '{print $3}')
```

But if I put that command in shell script and cron executes it, fcgiversion is blank? I added full paths to commands but still nothing, any idea ?

Comment: Have you searched a bit your problem on a search engine or here ? This is top 3 questions for unix-like

Comment: How are you checking the value of that variable in `cron`.

Comment: I'm just outputing it to some file with echo "$fcgiversion" >> /tmp/some_file

Comment: How do you execute the script from cron?

Comment: */1 * * * * /bin/sh /root/collect_data.sh  >> /dev/null 2>&1 &  

ps. it works if I add -l:  

    */1 * * * * /bin/sh /root/collect_data.sh  >> /dev/null 2>&1 &  

but can it work without -l?

Comment: Are you `cd`ing to the right directory so that the `Version.*` matches the right files?

Comment: @Robert, you are wrong. The grep command looks into the output of the python program, not into any file. But it is true that wildcard should be quoted.

Comment: @zbuzanic, as you are smart enough to dump the output of the entire pipe into a file, I think you do not need any help to do the same with the output of each command of that pipe ;)